# How do I automatically say the knock knock jokes, with a delay of one second?

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

In the Java networking tutorial, [we find the KnockKnock Client/Server pair](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html). So I want to sit back and have the KnockKnockClient automatically send the clues to the server classes (which are KnockKnockServer/KnockKnockProtocol ). Here is what I tried :

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class KnockKnockClientRedone {


  static String KKJokes[] =  { "Who's there?", "Turnip who?", "y", "Who's there?", "Little Old Lady who?", "y", "Who's there?", "Doctor who?", "y" }; 

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


    Socket kkSocket = null;
    PrintWriter out = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {

      kkSocket = new Socket("localhost", 4444);
      out = new PrintWriter(kkSocket.getOutputStream(), true);

      for (int i = 0; i< KKJokes.length; i++) {
           try {
                Thread.sleep(1500);        }
           catch(Exception e){
             e.printStackTrace(); 
               }
           in =  new BufferedReader( 
                    new InputStreamReader( 
                        new ByteArrayInputStream(
                              KKJokes[i].getBytes()) ) ); 


    }

    } //try

    catch ( IOException io ){
       System.err.println("Calling IO . toString " + io.toString());  //System
       System.exit(1);
    }//catch

    BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String fromServer;
    String fromServer2;
    String fromUser;


    while ((fromServer = in.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println("Server: " + fromServer);

      if (fromServer.equals("bye."))
          break;

      fromUser = stdIn.readLine();

      if (fromUser != null){
          System.out.println("Client: " + fromUser);
          out.println(fromUser);
      }
    }

    out.close();
    in.close();
    stdIn.close();
    kkSocket.close();        
         }

}
```

But I noticed that something is wrong with my code here :

```
       in =  new BufferedReader( 
                new InputStreamReader( 
                    new ByteArrayInputStream(
                          KKJokes[i].getBytes()) ) );
```

It only loops through til the end, and then `in` contains the last String in the String array. What I need is for the Client to send a String over the client, then proceed to the next String *only* when the Server sends back. Since I'm on a local machine, I thought that a delay of 1 second would be sufficient.

Any tips appreciated thanks

Comment: So basically TCP networking

Comment: The code you have here just opens a socket to the server. It does not read anything from there and does not write anything to the server. 
My advice is for you to follow the Java tutorials for a simple echo server and client to see how sockets work: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html and if you have problems them come back with questions